# RegExp "/g" not working for string.search

Tags: javascript, regex, string

string.search() does not work for me when trying to find all occurrences:

```
   var test = "This is a sample text";
   var result = test.search(/ /g);
   // result = "4"
```

but it works for string.matches()

```
   var test = "This is a sample text";
   var result = test.match(/ /g);
   // result = " , , , "
```

What's the reason? Isn't it provided to find all occurrences in string.search(), or am I doing a mistake?

Some background: I'm trying to find the indices of all whitespaces (and later all "-" ) in a string, to capitalise the following character afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

[`String#search` returns the position of the first occurrence of the specified `searchvalue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search), or -1 if no match is found. It doesn't matter whether you use `/g` or not it will still return  position of the first occurrence only.

Answer (score 0):

"If successful, search returns the index of the first match of the regular expression inside the string. Otherwise, it returns -1."
From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search